# Como colocar notificações em um aplicativo Android?

Tags: android, android-notification

Gostaria de saber como desenvolver notificações para um *app* Android, de modo que possa serem atualizadas online. Ou seja: Cada vez que houver uma atualização do *app*, gostaria que aparecesse uma notificação semelhante a essa da imagem.

[image: Exemplo de Notificação]

Comment: Mostre-nos a pesquisa que você já fez. Embora a sua pergunta seja clara não demonstra nenhum esforço de desenvolvimento.

Comment: @AntonioAlexandreAlonsodeSi
Nas minhas pesquisas encontrei somente formas de desenvolver popup na tela com o comando "alertdialog". Quero fazer notificações na barra de tarefas

Answer (score 3):

Nada melhor que a documentação da própria Google.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html

Você pode fazer desde notificações com o layout padrão(lembrando que o layout padrão muda de versão para versão do Android, ou seja, esse layout ai dessa imagem não vai ser o mesmo para a versão 6.0, por exemplo) até notificações com layout personalizado.

Enquanto a ação que vai disparar a notificação, isso ai já é da lógica do seu app.

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia utilizar o firebases pra isso, acho bastante limitado.

Melhor usar o Signal One. https://onesignal.com/ - https://documentation.onesignal.com/

Tutorial facil de seguir - http://www.thiengo.com.br/onesignal-para-notificacoes-em-massa-no-android